# JNI Callback Threads

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have some java code that calls a jni layer.

The JNI layer is a 3rd party so I can't inspect it, but at some point it creates a new thread and makes a callback to the java code.

Inside this callback method I try to create another java thread and call start on the thread. However this java thread never gets run. Its like it never exists.

Is creating threads from JNI call backs a problem ?

I can create a threadpoolexecutor with a core size and put the task on the executor instead but I'd like to know why I can't create threads inside the callback.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `AttachCurrentThread()` inside the callback before it calls any other JNI method, and `DetachCurrentThread()` before it exits.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable solution, it these methods were not called would the callback to the JVM still work , but not allow thread creation inside that callback ?

Comment: @user594950 There's nothing in the JNI Specification that says it will work at all without these methods.

Comment: These are comments with got back from our third party, they seem to suggest that they are making the correct calls. "We get the VM using JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs().  We then attach to the current thread (AttachCurrentThread) then call the java callback with the session and event. After we call the callback function, we call DetachCurrentThread()."                                                                                                                  Is there any other reason why we wouldn't be able to create a thread from the callback ?

Comment: @madlad Are they doing that via all possible execution paths, including error returns?